# How to position widget inside Stack relative to center?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

```
Stack(
  children: [  
      Positioned(
        left: ??? + 20,
        child: Text('This text is 20 pixel left to the center of the stack'),
      ),
  ],
),
```

I am trying to position widget inside Stack relative to center.

How to get `???` in the above code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will want to use the [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) widget which will build at layout time and provides the parent widget's constraints.

[image: demo]

Try something like

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  double _constIconSize = 50;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          print(constraints);
          return Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              //Exact center
              Positioned(
                top: constraints.constrainHeight() / 2 - _constIconSize / 2,
                left: constraints.constrainWidth() / 2 - _constIconSize / 2,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.gps_fixed,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  size: _constIconSize,
                ),
              ),
              //100 right and 50  bottom from center
              Positioned(
                top: constraints.constrainHeight() / 2 + 100,
                left: constraints.constrainWidth() / 2 + 50,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.face,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: _constIconSize,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way of doing it

```
     Positioned(
        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 + 20,
        child:
            Text('This text is 20 pixel left to the center of the stack'),
      ),
```